# Universal date format mask for manual date input

Tags: java, android

Is there way in Android to dynamically enter and format date for `EditText` based on locale?The intent is to create manual date input `EditText` locale based.

There are various of patterns for example:

```
2021-10-22    y-MM-dd        -    ce_RU
22.10.21      dd.MM.yy       -    de_LI
22/10/2021    dd/MM/y        -    en_001
21. 10. 22.   yy. M. d.      -    ko_KP
[10/22/21]    [M/d/yy]       -    en_XA
2021/10/22    y/M/d          -    zh_CN_#Hans
22.10.21 г.   d.MM.yy 'г'.   -    bg_BG
```

We can show formatted date text for all locales but cannot manually enter pre-formatted text date based on locale?

Comment: Can you please post an example ?

Comment: What’s stopping you? I am sorry, it is possible, so I don’t understand the question?

Comment: @OleV.V. I will try

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, None of the DateFormat does the conversion of M to MM or d to dd. You can do it by writing if else blocks.

Anyway, Since you already have the pattern in string, you can convert it to desired format using regex before doing the parsing.

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getContext());
String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();
pattern = pattern.replaceAll("(?i)(M)+","M").replaceAll("M", "MM");
pattern = pattern.replaceAll("(?i)(y)+","y").replaceAll("y", "yyyy");
pattern = pattern.replaceAll("(?i)(d)+","d").replaceAll("d", "dd");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may help, thanks, btw for what used one letter in `SimpleDateFormat`(d/M/y)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Here is the expansion for each letter. May be I'm not getting your question ? Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I mean for example, why `d` and `dd` show same result = `22`

Comment: The different is in single digit. Example: d/MM/yyyy for 5/06/1997. dd/MM/yyyy => 05/06/1997

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Sure. Understand your point. It was not me suggesting simpledateformat. It was in the question and I just extended on it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see the first versions of the question, or I would instead have posted a comment under the question warning against the old and troublesome classes. The references to `DateFormat` and `SimplDateFormat` have later been deleted from the question.